# Language switch using cookie but only visible after manual page refresh

Tags: php, codeigniter, cookies, codeigniter-2, multilingual

So I'm using the language detection / cookie method for setting the user language:

1. User arrives on page
2. Check if user has a cookie user_lang set
3. If set, use that language
4. If not set use language detection function and set cookie

Language switch:

1. User goes to /change/language/[languageshortcode]
2. Verify the language shortcode is valid, delete/change previous cookie and update with new language
3. load page

The problem is that I can see that the user_lang cookie has indeed changed from e.g. EN to FR but the actual language switch only happens if I manually refresh the page.

On my local setup the change is immediately, on my remote server I have to refresh.

Thinks I've changed that I thought caused this:

- Disabled all forms of page caching
- Disabled Varnish Cache serverside using htaccess
- Actually delete the cookie and set a new one instead of just changing the cookie

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since no code is posted, I'm going to just provide a few thoughts.  One solution would be to add a JS page reload but only if some condition is true.  The better solution, however, is ensuring that if the user has made a change to the language, don't read the cookie to detect language for that page load (as it doesn't completely set until the script completes).  If the user has made a change, use the value that was used to set the cookie and ignore the cookie, if no changes were made, simply detect the cookie.  Does that make sense?

Comment: The strange thing is that it works perfectly on my local machine.

Comment: Did that solve the problem?  If not posting some code would allow for a little more assistance.